# Specifying a different pvalue color scale for each group in bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart, scale

I am trying to generate a bar plot that looks similar to the one below but mine will be colored by "sample" (in vitro, BAT and WAT in that order rather than BP, CC and MF).
[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQg1Y.jpg)
Each group will have the same scale limits representing pvalue (0.0001 - 0.1) but the scale for each group (in vitro, BAT, WAT) will be colored differently like in the sample plot. Each group should also be ordered by significance which I already specified. I managed to generate the following plot which is almost there. I just need to figure out how to specify a different scale color for each "sample" group.
[current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIjUn.jpg)

```
cell_cycle_sample <- structure(list(sample = c("WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", "WAT", 
"WAT", "WAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", 
"BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "BAT", "in_vitro", "in_vitro", 
"in_vitro", "in_vitro", "in_vitro"), label = structure(1:52, .Label = c("KEGG_CELL_CYCLE(WAT)(123)", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_G2_G2_M_PHASES(WAT)(183)", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE_CHECKPOINTS(WAT)(286)", 
"REACTOME_M_PHASE(WAT)(390)", "REACTOME_NUCLEAR_ENVELOPE_NE_REASSEMBLY(WAT)(65)", 
"REACTOME_SEPARATION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATIDS(WAT)(187)", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE(WAT)(601)", 
"REACTOME_POSTMITOTIC_NUCLEAR_PORE_COMPLEX_NPC_REFORMATION(WAT)(22)", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_METAPHASE_AND_ANAPHASE(WAT)(225)", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE(WAT)(199)", 
"REACTOME_RESOLUTION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATID_COHESION(WAT)(122)", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_SPINDLE_CHECKPOINT(WAT)(111)", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROMETAPHASE(WAT)(193)", 
"REACTOME_AMPLIFICATION_OF_SIGNAL_FROM_THE_KINETOCHORES(WAT)(94)", 
"HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V1(WAT)(197)", "HALLMARK_G2M_CHECKPOINT(WAT)(195)", 
"REACTOME_APC_C_CDH1_MEDIATED_DEGRADATION_OF_CDC20_AND_OTHER_APC_C_CDH1_TARGETED_PROTEINS_IN_LATE_MITOSIS_EARLY_G1(BAT)(74)", 
"REACTOME_ASSEMBLY_OF_THE_PRE_REPLICATIVE_COMPLEX(BAT)(83)", 
"REACTOME_RECOGNITION_OF_DNA_DAMAGE_BY_PCNA_CONTAINING_REPLICATION_COMPLEX(BAT)(30)", 
"REACTOME_APC_C_MEDIATED_DEGRADATION_OF_CELL_CYCLE_PROTEINS(BAT)(87)", 
"REACTOME_CYCLIN_D_ASSOCIATED_EVENTS_IN_G1(BAT)(44)", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_SPINDLE_CHECKPOINT(BAT)(111)", 
"REACTOME_RESOLUTION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATID_COHESION(BAT)(122)", 
"REACTOME_G1_S_DNA_DAMAGE_CHECKPOINTS(BAT)(67)", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROPHASE(BAT)(121)", 
"REACTOME_DNA_REPLICATION_PRE_INITIATION(BAT)(98)", "REACTOME_G1_S_TRANSITION(BAT)(106)", 
"REACTOME_RECRUITMENT_OF_NUMA_TO_MITOTIC_CENTROSOMES(BAT)(88)", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_G1_PHASE_AND_G1_S_TRANSITION(BAT)(130)", "REACTOME_G2_M_DNA_DAMAGE_CHECKPOINT(BAT)(90)", 
"REACTOME_DNA_REPLICATION(BAT)(126)", "REACTOME_G2_M_CHECKPOINTS(BAT)(163)", 
"REACTOME_S_PHASE(BAT)(148)", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_G2_G2_M_PHASES(BAT)(183)", 
"REACTOME_CYCLIN_A_CDK2_ASSOCIATED_EVENTS_AT_S_PHASE_ENTRY(BAT)(73)", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROMETAPHASE(BAT)(193)", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_METAPHASE_AND_ANAPHASE(BAT)(225)", 
"KEGG_CELL_CYCLE(BAT)(123)", "REACTOME_TP53_REGULATES_TRANSCRIPTION_OF_DNA_REPAIR_GENES(BAT)(43)", 
"REACTOME_M_PHASE(BAT)(390)", "REACTOME_DNA_REPAIR(BAT)(299)", 
"REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE_CHECKPOINTS(BAT)(286)", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE(BAT)(601)", 
"HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V1(BAT)(197)", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE(BAT)(199)", 
"HALLMARK_G2M_CHECKPOINT(BAT)(195)", "HALLMARK_E2F_TARGETS(BAT)(199)", 
"REACTOME_CELLULAR_SENESCENCE(invitro)(95)", "REACTOME_MITOTIC_PROMETAPHASE(invitro)(193)", 
"REACTOME_AMPLIFICATION_OF_SIGNAL_FROM_THE_KINETOCHORES(invitro)(94)", 
"REACTOME_RESOLUTION_OF_SISTER_CHROMATID_COHESION(invitro)(122)", 
"REACTOME_MITOTIC_SPINDLE_CHECKPOINT(invitro)(111)"), class = "factor"), 
    percent_ccgs = c(26.8, 26.2, 20.6, 19, 29.2, 21.9, 20.5, 
    40.9, 22.7, 22.6, 23, 21.6, 21.8, 22.3, 27.9, 25.6, 33.8, 
    32.5, 33.3, 34.5, 38.6, 24.3, 21.3, 31.3, 20.7, 31.6, 34, 
    27.3, 31.5, 21.1, 29.4, 25.2, 32.4, 29.5, 37, 25.4, 27.6, 
    32.5, 37.2, 25.9, 21.7, 24.8, 24.8, 27.9, 29.6, 30.3, 26.1, 
    28.4, 16.1, 19.1, 16.4, 18.9), kuiper_q = c(0.09611, 0.08737, 
    0.0695, 0.04749, 0.0278, 0.01853, 0.0139, 0.00927, 0.00927, 
    0.0068, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.083925532, 
    0.067253165, 0.066876923, 0.066518421, 0.062635616, 0.0546, 
    0.054455882, 0.048555556, 0.042714286, 0.0406, 0.036672222, 
    0.03521875, 0.03442069, 0.03442069, 0.027906667, 0.025044444, 
    0.01932, 0.01932, 0.01932, 0.0161, 0.010733333, 0.007542857, 
    1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 
    0.0125, 0.0122, 0.0012, 8e-04, 2e-04)), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), class = "data.frame")

#import data
cell_cycle_sample <- read.csv("cell_cycle_sample.csv")
# make label an ordered factor
cell_cycle_sample$label <- factor(cell_cycle_sample$label, levels = cell_cycle_sample$label)
#specify scalebreaks
b <- c(0.0001, 0, 0.1)
#generate plot
ggplot(cell_cycle_sample,aes(x=percent_ccgs,y=label,fill=kuiper_q,group=sample)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge",width=0.4,linewidth=0.7) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(0.0001,0.1),
                       colours=c("navyblue", "darkmagenta", "darkorange1"),
                       breaks=b, labels=format(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to generate a new scale for each `sample` in your data. We'll do this using the `ggnewscale` package.

For each within your `sample`, we'll do a separate call to `geom_col`, subsetting the data, moving the `aes(fill=)` from the main call to each `geom_col`. We'll also set the gradient for each as well.

```r
ggplot(cell_cycle_sample, aes(x=percent_ccgs, y=label, group=sample)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge", width=0.4, linewidth=0.7, aes(fill = kuiper_q),
           data = ~ subset(.x, sample == "WAT")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    name = "BAT", guide = guide_colorbar(order = 3),
    limits = c(0.0001, 0.1),
    low = "blue", high = "lightblue",
    breaks=b, labels = format(b)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(position="dodge", width=0.4, linewidth=0.7, aes(fill = kuiper_q),
           data = ~ subset(.x, sample == "BAT")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    name = "WAT", guide = guide_colorbar(order = 2),
    limits = c(0.0001, 0.1),
    low = "green", high = "lightgreen",
    breaks=b, labels = format(b)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(position="dodge", width=0.4, linewidth=0.7, aes(fill = kuiper_q),
           data = ~ subset(.x, sample == "in_vitro")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    name = "in_vitro", guide = guide_colorbar(order = 1),
    limits = c(0.0001, 0.1),
    low = "red", high = "pink",
    breaks=b, labels = format(b))
```

[image]

Notes:

- I don't know if I assigned the correct colors, labels or order of `sample` groups, over to you for updating the label titles.
- Realize that `guide_colorbar(order=)` is from bottom-to-top, though I believe you are ordering the bars themselves with your `factor`s. Play around, you should be able to achieve any order you want.
- I admit that I don't know why I need to move `aes(fill = kuiper_q)` from the main call to each `geom_col`, but it doesn't work without that change.
- The `data=~ subset(...)` is based on two things: `ggplot2` using `rlang`'s tilde functions, where the `.x` here is replaced by the data provided in the main `ggplot(...)` call, and I'm using `subset` because I didn't know if you are already using `dplyr` (and you don't need it just for this). You could also remove the original `cell_cycle_sample` from the main call and for each `geom_call` so `data = subset(cell_cycle_sample, sample == "BAT")` (etc). However ... if you have other geoms/layers that need something in the data, this becomes a little more onerous, so ... I kept it this way.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans .   It worked except that the bars are not grouped by "sample". I believe that they are just in there alphabetically? I tried making "label" an ordered factor (like I do in my original code) but nothing changes. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't understand ... the `label`s are precisely in the same order as your plot, and they are (I think "clearly"?) grouped by `sample`.

Comment: You are explicitly controlling the order with the levels of your `label` factor; the only order I impose on that is by adding each of `sample` one by one, which controls the order of the groups.

Comment: I'm not sure what is doing this... In your example it is correct and but when I run it with the same data the groups are colored properly (a separate color for each of the three groups) but the order of the "labels" are alphabetically ranked and not kept in the same order as my dataframe. I'm perplexed.

Comment: "alphabetically ranked" suggests no `factor` on that field, verify you set the `factor` and its `levels=` appropriately